# What is the correct way to create a reactive chain for a process that includes UI modal dialogs and long-running tasks?

Tags: android, rx-java2

Reactive programming with RxJava helps create nice and concise code for business processes that include UI dialogs and long-running async tasks. However, Android UI has its peculiarities that can break the process. A simplified example:

```
public void onProcessWasInitiatedByUser() {

    someCompletableSource.startAndWaitForSomeLongProcess()
                         .flatMap(showModalDialogAndWaitForAnswer())
                         .flatMap(startAndWaitForSomeOtherLongProcess())
                         .flatMap(showAnotherModalDialogAndWaitForAnswer())
                         .subscribe(() -> {
                              // finalize the process after the user has entered and confirmed all the required data
                         });

}
```

Note: `subscribeOn()` and `observeOn()` not included in the example for brevity. I know that mixed UI + background processes will require thread switching to avoid UI freezes and direct UI calls from background threads.

The questions:

1. Considering that `startAndWaitForSomeProcess` might last long enough for the device to go to sleep, there is a very high chance to get a `java.lang.IllegalStateException` if attempting to show a modal dialog. **How to ensure that modal dialog is displayed when the user unlocks the device, but still to keep the modal dialog as part of this Rx flow?**

In theory, I've heard it is recommended to use viewmodels to solve UI lifecycle issues but I'm not sure how it would help in this situation. Ok, I can store the data inside a viewmodel and later show the dialog when the device wakes up... but then how do I continue with the same Rx flow that was started in `onProcessWasInitiatedByUser`? I would prefer not to break the flow into separate pieces and scatter them around some other event handlers. What should I do inside `showModalDialogAndWaitForAnswer` function to make them safe for locked screen cases and still wait for the answer from the user?

2. Less important - I'm not sure if my example is the nicest way to organize this. Is there any rule of thumb, when things should go inside `flatMap` and when should be left for the final `subscribe`, or when `subscribe` should be left entirely empty; or when it's best to use some different RxJava function? How do experienced RxJava developers organize it to avoid ambiguities and possible caveats?

Answer (score 1):

Great questions. Here my observations:

1. *startAndWaitForSomeProcess* is an operation that should be executed in the background and a separate context that, once finished, notify the client (View). In this case, what you need is probably a [background task](https://developer.android.com/guide/background) or a **[Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)**.

Rx helps you to orchestrate both synchronous and asynchronous processes in the same or different Scheduler contexts. I do not recommend using it for this requirement since it would imply an extended **UI blocking time**, and the operations life cycle would be unmanageable.

2. It is recommended that conversations with UI be made through the subscribed *Observer*, not through the operator's chain, as side effects may induce bugs. I've written a useful guide called "**The Clean Way to Use Rx**," and in Item 33: Negotiating with UI, it talks about it.

I hope that I have helped you.